# Storing a list of objects on appengine across all instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, storage, temporary-objects

I have an app on Google App Engine. It processes realtime data without any regard for past data(so no datastore/full persistency), and thus I don't need anything extremely reliable to recover data in case of an instance crash or new deployment.

I have multiple instances, due to the load, that need to share a single list of objects. I looked into memcached, but this requires a mapping from key to object in a map-style interface without the ability to dump all entries.

In addition, I'm hoping to make the entries expirable unless "bumped", though that can handle in user code.

What's a reasonable solution to this that doesn't involve the datastore? I'd prefer for it to be able to handle concurrent reads and writes, from multiple app engine instances(which is why a simple Java object declaration doesn't work as it's per-instance).

Memcached could potentially store a single object but it would require getting the object, getting some sort of lock, modifying it, and writing it back to the cache.

N.B. There is unrelated data in the presistent app engine datastore.

Clarification: I need *all* the entities. Entities themselves may be modified at any time, removed by expiration or semi-automatically, or created from scratch. I'm not particularly able to head for billable backends.

Edit: Yes, it would work with single lists stored locally but I expect spikes where multiple instances are needed. I'd need at least a best-effort approach to getting a full list, though I don't mind a delay of synchronization. However, round-robining communication between all instances sans backend would be relatively unscalable, and I'd be stuck in more of a rent-a-server scenario there.

I don't care if changes don't make it through immediately after a change is committed on another frontend instance. The changes would need to make it through with 100% certainty, however. I only see insertions and updates where a lastSeen value(long) is increased. The updates should also be replicated or reflected on all instances.

Note: The bounty got refunded due to the fact that I will unable to award it due to circumstances at that time, that I cannot control. I will re-add when possible.

Comment: memcache would seem to be it, there is CAS Compare-And-Set in Memcache service.  Doesn't give you the dump all entities - if you don't need recovery why do you need to dump all entities.  A backend could be another alternative, it maintains an in memory structure of the dataset and the front ends talk to it.

Comment: @TimHoffman I need to have a full list of entities. I need to present all 1000 or so to clients. I also would need to purchase extra quota for backends, right?

Comment: Yes, you will require extra quota for a backend.

Comment: @TimHoffman That, alas, is the problem. I'm currently huddled on free, and this being a personal project I'd prefer not to stretch myself thinner with a backend.

Comment: Do you know all the keys of the entities you need to cache/manipulate before hand ?

Comment: @TimHoffman Unfortunately, no. If I did, I'd need to distribute *that* list in this fashion, which brings me back to square one.

Comment: Note: The bounty got refunded due to the fact that I will unable to award it due to circumstances at that time, that I cannot control. I will re-add when possible.

Comment: HOnestly given the constraints you impose I don't believe appengine is a good fit.  Square peg - round hole.

Comment: @TimHoffman Distributing session keys at high speed between instances? Seems somewhat ubiquitous, but I guess if it's really a round hole, I can live with that... I'll still leave the question open

Comment: But you don't want to pay.  Its the free threshold and the volume of work constraint that means you have a round hole.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the datastore here?

If your concern is that you'll rack up too much expense having a lot of items in the db, just save each item with a `datetime_created` field with `auto_now_add=True` (or the Java equivalent; I come from Python), and schedule a cron to go through and delete anything old?

The Datastore is supposed to be highly available for concurrent reads and writes, as far as I'm aware.

You might also consider just moving off AppEngine. Redis sounds like the right tool for the job you're describing, and Elastic Beanstalk on AWS could probably handle your needs quite well there. Of course, it'd be more effort to get things set up, but likely not overwhelmingly so.

Comment: My concern for cost is not with storage amount but with number of operations. To get recent entries, this requires an index, and refreshing an entry(every entry is designed to refresh every 20 seconds from external requests) takes 4 datastore writes. Calculating this for 100 entries actively being refreshed from outside amounts to 1,728,000 datastore operations not to mention the indexed lookups for clients to read.